# express4 router skipping base route and going directly to a sub-route

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have an express4 router that is skipping the base route and going directly to a designated ./user route.   But I can not see why it is skipping the base route.

#### APP.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();
require('./routes')(app);
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
//app.use('/', router);
module.exports = app;
```

#### ./routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
// route middleware that will happen on every request
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // log each request to the console
    console.log(req.method, req.url);
    // continue doing what we were doing and go to the route
    next(); 
});
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log('inside the root route');
});
//module.exports = router;
module.exports = function(app) {
    // here we list our individual sets of routes to use in the router
    require('./route/user')(app);
};
```

When I run the app (npm start), console displays the log that resides inside the user route and totally skips the base route ('/').

Where did I go wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

It appears that you are only exporting the user routes.
To make this a bit clearer, app.js only has access to the following when you require routes.index.js:

```
function(app) {
    // here we list our individual sets of routes to use in the router
    require('./route/user')(app);
};
```

hence why it is skipping the base route entirely.

Following the [API documentation](http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html) (under the 'express.Router' section), the correct code to export the routes would be:

```
// exports the router.use and router.get('/) routes
module.exports = router
```

Which would mean you'd have to include the user routes in another section  (such as app.js).

Comment: Thank you Ashley.  Makes sense. This is what happens when you are not a full-time developer; you forget the simple stuff.